# How to properly make method async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have method for computing Levenshtein distance

```
public static LevenshteinMatches LevenshteinSingleThread(this string str, string expression, int maxDistance) {
        if (str.Length > expression.Length + 1) {
            int len = expression.Length;
            long strLen = str.Length - len + 1;
            int[] results = new int[strLen];
            int[][,] dimension = new int[strLen][,];
            for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                dimension[i] = new int[len + 1, len + 1];
            }

            string source = str;
            source = source.ToUpper();
            expression = expression.ToUpper();

            for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                results[i] = SqueareLevenshtein(ref dimension[i], str.Substring(i, len).ToUpper(), expression, len);
            }

            LevenshteinMatches matches = new LevenshteinMatches();

            for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                if (results[i] <= maxDistance) {
                    matches.addMatch(str.Substring(i, len), Math.Round((1.0 - ((double)results[i] / len)) * 100.0, 2), i, len, results[i]);
                }
            }

            return matches;
        }
        else {
            LevenshteinMatch match = str.LevenshteinCPU(expression, maxDistance);
            if (match != null)
                return new LevenshteinMatches(match);
            else
                return new LevenshteinMatches();
        }
    }
```

What should I do to make it async?

Or should i leave this method and just call it some different way?

Here is my attempt to make it async; Not sure what is wrong but I can't get any results - thread is inf working  but it should take only few ms.

```
public static async Task<LevenshteinMatches> LevenshteinSingleThread(this string str, string expression, int maxDistance) {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            if (str.Length > expression.Length + 1) {
                int len = expression.Length;
                long strLen = str.Length - len + 1;
                int[] results = new int[strLen];
                int[][,] dimension = new int[strLen][,];
                for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                    dimension[i] = new int[len + 1, len + 1];
                }

                string source = str;
                source = source.ToUpper();
                expression = expression.ToUpper();

                for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                    results[i] = SqueareLevenshtein(ref dimension[i], str.Substring(i, len).ToUpper(), expression, len);
                }

                LevenshteinMatches matches = new LevenshteinMatches();

                for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                    if (results[i] <= maxDistance) {
                        matches.addMatch(str.Substring(i, len), Math.Round((1.0 - ((double)results[i] / len)) * 100.0, 2), i, len, results[i]);
                    }
                }

                return matches;
            }
            else {
                LevenshteinMatch match = str.LevenshteinCPU(expression, maxDistance);
                if (match != null)
                    return new LevenshteinMatches(match);
                else
                    return new LevenshteinMatches();
            }
        });
    }
```

rest of the code [link](https://pastebin.com/vkqhAyKm)

And that's how I call it:

```
string s = "xcjavxzcbvmrmummuuutmtumuumtryumtryumtrutryumtryumtrymutryumtyumtryumtrmutyumtrurtmutymurtmyutrymut";

        s = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, 4000));

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var ret = s.LevenshteinSingleThread("jas", 1);
        var res = ret.Result;
        watch.Stop();



        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: With your second example you're likely deadlocking if your calling the code like that from a UI context. You need to `await ret` instead of `.Result`.

Comment: You *don't* make the method asynchronous.  Nothing about what that method is doing is actually asynchronous.

Comment: It would seem that your code is CPU bound and unsuited to async await. You may however gain some benefit by parallelizing certain hotspots?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing async about your function, it is entirely CPU bound work. Changing the signature to `async Task<LevenshteinMatches>` and never using `await` in the function should have caused a warning in the compiler.

Instead of "making it async" if the thing you are really after is making it work in parallel then just call the code in parallel.

```
string s = "xcjavxzcbvmrmummuuutmtumuumtryumtryumtrutryumtryumtrymutryumtyumtryumtrmutyumtrurtmutymurtmyutrymut";
s = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, 4000));

var expressions = new[] {"jas", "cbv"}

var tasks = new List<Task<LevenshteinMatches>>()
foreach(var expression in expressions)
{
   var task = new Task.Run(()=> message.LevenshteinSingleThread(expression, 1)); //Start multiple threads
   tasks.Add(task);
}
LevenshteinMatches[] results = Task.WaitAll(tasks); //Wait for all the threads to end.
```

You could even make parts of the internal function multi-threaded by using `Parallel.For(` to make some of the for loops parallel, just be careful that any collections you call `Add` on are either synchronized inside a `lock` or are thread safe collections.

For example if `SqueareLevenshtein` is thread safe internally you could do

```
Parallel.For(0, strLen, i => {
                                   //Are you sure ref is needed here?
    results[i] = SqueareLevenshtein(ref dimension[i], str.Substring(i, len).ToUpper(), expression, len);
});

LevenshteinMatches matches = new LevenshteinMatches();

Parallel.For(0, strLen; i => {
    if (results[i] <= maxDistance) {
        lock(matches)
        {
            matches.addMatch(str.Substring(i, len), Math.Round((1.0 - ((double)results[i] / len)) * 100.0, 2), i, len, results[i]);
        }
    }
});

return matches;
```

Comment: I used ref because i wanted multiple threads to work on separate slices, but can be removed now